# Compile Ceylon Js Code with Google Closure Compiler in Advanced Mode

Tags: google-closure-compiler, ceylon

What is the recommended way to optimally minimize the size of ceylon javascript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed the language module through a minifier once (can't remember which one, some online service) and some tests failed after that. But this was before splitting the model from the code, and IIRC the errors were related to the model being minified; so maybe it can work for you if you only minify the code, but leave the model alone.